# Apply function to row of SparkR data frame

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a clever way to apply an R function to each row of a SparkR data frame? I would like to be able to use functions like `preProcess` and `predict` from the `caret` library.

```
    df <- SparkR::createDataFrame(sqlContext, mtcars)
    rdd <- SparkR:::toRDD(df)
    processed.rdd <- SparkR:::map(rdd, preProcess)
```

The data frame is as I would expect, but the format of the data in the RDD has changed to a list of columns.

```
    > first(df)
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
    1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4

    > first(rdd)
    $mpg
    [1] 21

    $cyl
    [1] 6
    ...
```

and `preProcess` does not handle this format:

```
    > processed.rdd <- SparkR:::map(rdd, preProcess)
    Error in UseMethod("preProcess") : 
      no applicable method for 'preProcess' applied to an object of class "list"
    Calls: source ... func -> FUN -> f -> func -> lapply -> lapply -> FUN
    Execution halted
```